# ITextSharp - PDF writing over Header Area beyond first page

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, pdf-generation, itext

I've been working with ITextSharp and using it to generate PDFs - however I recently encountered an issue where the top margin of all pages beyond the first seem to be ignored and as a result writing occurs over my header.

**Current margins:**

```
document.SetMargins(72,72, 36, 36);
```

It should be noted that the left and right margins work perfectly beyond the first page - however it seems to ignore the top margin and begin the text at the top of the page (where the header occurs).

Does anyone have any insights as to why this might occur? Or is there an area or event that I could use to reinforce the document margins for each page? (Perhaps the `OnStartPage` event?)

I would be glad to provide any additional code if needed - as I know that ITextSharp can become very convoluted code-wise.

Comment: A small, stand alone example would be nice to illustrate your issue: basically, the method you use to generate 2 pages worth of content, and the event listener where the `OnStartPage` event is caught. As a sidenote, it's generally preferred to add headers and footers in the `OnEndPage` event listener.

Comment: I'll have an example PDF to attempt to demonstrate what is going on. Currently I have the Header being added within OnStartPage and the Footer being added within OnEndPage; does that seem right?

Comment: As I said, it's generally preferred to add both headers and footers within `OnEndPage`, once all the content is already included on the page.

Comment: I'll try switching those around as well. Thanks Alexis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue as per Alexis Pigeon's instructions of including the Header and Footers into the `OnEndPage` event as opposed to each of them being in a separate event. I also adjusted the margins (increasing the bottom margin) to prevent the overwriting.

Answer (score 3):

If you want different margins on different, I hooked the OnPageStart event and set the margin there depending on the page number.

```
internal class DocumentEvents : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [start page].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The writer.</param>
    /// <param name="document">The document.</param>
    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        if (document.PageNumber == 1)
        {
            document.SetMargins(40f, 40f, 130f, 20f);
        }
        else
        {
            document.SetMargins(40f, 40f, 30f, 30f);
        }

        document.NewPage();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to wire up your event to the document writer:

```
this.writer.PageEvent = new DocumentEvents();
```